# Don't understand why this code is working

Tags: javascript, local-storage

If the user's browser is IE, and the localStorage doesn't already exist, the following code sets a localStorage, which has an expiry date of 24 hours.

```
(function ieAlert() {
  var lastclear = window.localStorage.getItem('myLocalStorage'),
  time_now  = (new Date()).getTime();

  var isIE = document.documentMode

  if (isIE && !lastclear) {    
    if ((time_now - lastclear) > 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24) {
      window.localStorage.clear()
      window.localStorage.setItem('myLocalStorage', time_now)
    }
  }
})()
```

It works.
But what I don't understand is this part:

```
if (isIE && !lastclear) {    
    if ((time_now - lastclear) > 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24) {
      window.localStorage.clear()
      window.localStorage.setItem('myLocalStorage', time_now)
    }
  }
```

Here the `lastclear` is undefined, how does the calculation works then?

Comment: Bigger question would be why would you do that in the first place? Logic doesn't make sense

Comment: @charlietfl - I assume there's more logic we don't see...

Comment: @T.J.Crowder yeah... if variable is "not defined", compare its value :) totally logical.

Comment: `ieAlert`, `lastclear`, `time_now` Only PascalCasing is "missing"; *but not missed at all*. Please, choose a style *(the first one)* no matter which one *(first one!!!)* and go with it, but don't mix like that.

Comment: Hahahha, indeed. Thanks for pointing out this.

Answer (score 10):

> Here the `lastclear` is undefined, how does the calculation works then?

No, it's `null`. [`getItem`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Storage/getItem) returns `null` for entries that don't exist. In a numeric context, `null` coerces to `0`, so `number - null` is `number - 0` is `number`.

(Whereas if the original author had accessed it the other way, `localStorage.myLocalStorage`, the value would indeed have been `undefined`, and the `>` wouldn't work because `number - undefined` is `NaN`, and all comparisons with `NaN` result in `false`.)

If I were writing the code, I wouldn't rely on that `null` coercion part of it, not least because it trips up future readers of the code (as it tripped you up). But that's why it works.

Comment: number - undefined = NaN

Comment: @FlashThunder - Yup. I don't know if the original author knew that and used `getItem` specifically because of the `null` return, or used it and then saw the `null` return, or what. It's definitely not how **I** would have written the code. :-)

Comment: What about this: if (isIE && lastclear === null) {...} ? Would it be a better logic?

Comment: Thanks for your answers. But what would be a better way to compare the expiry date of a localStorage?

Comment: @user1941537 - To be able to provide useful input, we'd have to know what the code was *meant* to do, because it seems fairly likely it doesn't do what it was meant to do. For instance, the above could be just `if (document.documentMode && !localStorage.getItem("myLocalStorage")) { localStorage.clear(); localStorage.setItem("myLocalStorage", Date.now()); }` because that's basically what it does, the entire second `if` is pointless. (But real feedback on improving the logic would be a different question entirely.)

Comment: @user1941537 - *"But what would be a better way to compare the expiry date of a localStorage?"* Well, again, that would be a different question. The code in the question doesn't do that. But for instance: `if (document.documentMode) {
    var last = +localStorage.getItem("last_time") || 0;
    var now = Date.now();
    if (!last || (now - last) > threshold) {
        localStorage.setItem("last_time", now);
        /*...do something...*/
    }
}`

Comment: Why do I need the + before locaStorage.getItem ?

Comment: @user1941537 - That converts the string from local storage into a number.